# Implementation of Linear Regression Using Gradient Descent

Tags: python-3.x, function, arraylist, linear-regression, gradient-descent

Linear Regression Using Gradient Descent

Reference: [Linear Regression Using Gradient Descent in 10 Lines of Code](https://towardsdatascience.com/linear-regression-using-gradient-descent-in-10-lines-of-code-642f995339c0)

Dataset:

House price    No. of bedrooms

Coding environment:  Google Co- lab

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import io
from google.colab import files 
uploaded = files.upload()
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['datasets_46927_85203_data.csv'])) 
house_price=df.price
No_of_bedrooms=df.bedrooms
# Mean of house_price and No_of_bedrooms
mean_x= np.mean(house_price)
mean_y=np.mean(No_of_bedrooms)

#Total number of datapoints
n=len(house_price)
numerator = 0;
denominator = 0;
for i in range (n):
  numerator += (house_price[i] - mean_x) * (No_of_bedrooms[i] - mean_y)
  denominator += (house_price[i] - mean_x) ** 2
slope= numerator / denominator
constant = mean_y - (slope*mean_x)
def linear_regression(house_price[], y, m_current=slope, b_current=constant, epochs=1000,
learning_rate=0.0001):
     N = float(len(No_of_bedrooms))
     for i in range(epochs):
          y_current = (m_current * house_price[i]) + b_current
          cost = sum([data**2 for data in (No_of_bedrooms[i]-y_current)]) / N
          m_gradient = -(2/N) * sum(house_price[i] * (No_of_bedrooms[i] - y_current))
          b_gradient = -(2/N) * sum(No_of_bedrooms[i] - y_current)
          m_current = m_current - (learning_rate * m_gradient)
          b_current = b_current - (learning_rate * b_gradient)
     return m_current, b_current, cost
```

Error: `def linear_regression(house_price[], y, m_current=slope, b_current=constant, epochs=1000, learning_rate=0.0001):`

```
Error Statement: File "<ipython-input-6-864b867cbc7a>", line 31
    

def linear_regression(house_price[], y, m_current=slope, b_current=constant, epochs=1000, learning_rate=0.0001):
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I haven't understand how to get rid of this error.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58996556/implementing-a-linear-regression-using-gradient-descent) has no connection with my query.

It will be great if someone helps me out. Thank you.

Comment: Often the syntax error is on a line prior to the one shown in the error message - particularly when you have unmatched parens/brackets somewhere. you figured out your previous problem/question regasrfing `R**2`??

Comment: `house_price[]` looks suspicious did you intend `linear_regression(house_price=[]`? or just  `linear_regression(house_price, y,...`?

Comment: @wwii There are two parameters in my program house_price which is an independent variable (x) and No_of_bedrooms which is a dependent variable (y).

Comment: Te parameter, `house_price[]`, in the function definition is not valid it **is** a syntax error.

Comment: @wwii can you please elaborate what do mean by function definition  is not valid. I believe, house_price is a vector which have more than one values. Therefore, I have written that like these. Can you please suggest me the correct syntax?

Comment: See my previous comment.  Change to `def linear_regression(house_price,...)`.

Comment: Yeah it works. But can you please explain the reason?

Comment: `houseprice[]` is not a [valid identifier](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers). [Parameters in function definitions have to be valid identifiers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions)